# How to upgrade Laravel 5.0.* to 5.2.* or later

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

My Application is built with Laravel version 5.0.35 and I want it to update to version 5.2.*

How can I do this?? Can I just replace `'5.0.*'` to `'5.2.*'` in composer.json file and then command `composer update`, will this work?? If not, then is there any way with which I can upgrade easily and automatically?? Please guide me step by step if possible...

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely not as easy as changing `5.0.*` to `5.2.*`. In the the documentation there is an [upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade) available. As you can see there are quite a few steps needed to go from `5.0` to `5.2` or higher.

You could also use [Laravel Shift](https://laravelshift.com/) to make pull requests to your project to update to the version you want. Please note this is a paid service.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to upgrade right away from 5.0.* to 5.2.*. You should upgrade your app in multi steps:

- [from Laravel 5.0 to 5.1](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.0)
- [from Laravel 5.1 to 5.1.11](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.1.11)
- [from Laravel 5.1 to 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/upgrade#upgrade-5.2.0)

It seems also Laravel Shift mentioned in post above does not offer this upgrade in once step - first you need to order update from 5.0 to 5.1 and then from 5.1 to 5.2